# Springboot, how to log and catch a beaninstantiationexception?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an autowired constructor where the params are loaded from the `application.properties` file. I'm randomly seeing NPEs in the constructor and transitively getting a `BeanInstantiationException` as a result.

Is it possible to intercept this failure so I can add logs and kill the pod that is running this code? As a result, my app just hangs indefinitely.

```
  @Autowired
  public GraphClient(
      @Value("${thing1}") String t1,
      @Value("${thing2}") int t2,
      @Value("${thing3}") boolean t3,
      @Value("${thing4}") boolean t4,
      @Value("${thing5}") int t5) {
```

Comment: Are you saying the app does not exit? Can you show us the exception trace once along with where it says that it is running?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class will enable us to catch any Exception that happened in our app.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(BeanInstantiationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity catchBeanInstantiationException() {
        // add log
        // do anything you want
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to do anything else beyond defining this class at all or is this sufficient?

Comment: Why are you assuming that it's an MVC application. It can very well be an event listener for example.

Comment: @John Just create the file, and define it as `@ControllerAdvice`, It allow us to catch all your exception in a single file. Simply define any exception you want to catch

Comment: @PrashantPandey still available to catch right? As long the application is a Spring Framework